# Adaptive Filter input vectors and iteration

Tags: python, algorithm, filtering, signal-processing, perceptron

I am trying to implement an adaptive filter for noise cancellation, in particular a RLS filter to remove motion artifacts from a signal. To do this I am reading some literature, there is one thing I don't understand and every book or article I found just asumes I already now this.

I have a reference signal represented as a list in Python of about 8000 elements, or samples. I need to input this to the RLS filter, but every algorithm I find always talks about the input vector as

> **X**[n] = [x1[n], x2[n], x3[n], ........, xM[n]]T

Where **X** is the input vector, and n is a time instant. And here is where I get lost. If n is a time instant, it would mean x[n] is an element in the list, a salmple. But if that is the case, what are x1, x2, ...., xM???.

I realise this is not strictly a coding problem, but I hope someone can help!

Thanks...

Comment: Just a guess but if n is the time indication, than X1, X2,..,Xm could be multiple measurements? Where did you read this?

Comment: Ok, I think I got it... Call N the order of the filter, then n from 0 to N is actually the iteration of the filter, how many times you run it. And to each iteration you feed the a window of x, called X[n]. where x1, x2, etc are the samples in that window. I implemented this window like this: X = x[n:n-N:-1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your explanation is correct.  The X input vector is multiplied recursively by the filter coefficients.  It's been some time since I wrote an adaptive filter, but if I remember correctly you're multiplying `M` filter coefficients by the latest `M` input values to get an update.

So `M` is the order of your filter, or the number of filter coefficients, and `n` is the length of the signal you are filtering.  And as you note your recursive filter will look at a 'window' of those input values for each filtered output calculation.